# Java - Url to String with any response code

Tags: java, http

I want to get the text of a url with java.

```
 public static String getResponseFromUrlDesktop(String url) {
    try {
        URL website = new URL(url);
        URLConnection connection = website.openConnection();


        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                        connection.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            response.append(inputLine);

        in.close();

        return response.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I go to an URL and it gives me 
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL

If I open the url in broswer I get a text. 
How can I always get the text of a GET request no matter the response code?

Comment: What's the `url` value?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/) tutorial will point you in the right direction.

Comment: @kocko the URL that i want to read its GET response

Comment: @npinti I saw that link, but I'm getting the same error, how can I get the text of a URL if I don't get the response code 200?

Comment: Could you post the url here ?

Comment: Here you go: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/20531316728/feed?filter=app_2392950137&fields=message&access_token=CAACEdEose0cBAHGp8ZAZCztnA9nI2tEvKQvbiP1LJYV1R8J17YOYJDYZBa3p3yFv0TxcRdOE07mitVV6KAjBhypavQsHnYXNFjUToacPy8QZBqfZCeQgDxPRP241WMVXSbcga6QXhajgQ3IkPN2M8lL0OortfTvFSKK65BYwYtgTDwSKNwXCQj0vZCameiZA66oE1ybD9XVVtdsF5YJaCJeY5ZBAgiaB5bIZD Is a facebook graph api URL, with an bad access token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 public static String getResponseFromUrlDesktop(String url) {

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            URL website = new URL(url);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) website.openConnection();

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    connection.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                response.append(inputLine);

            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                if (connection.getResponseCode() >= 400) {
                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            connection.getErrorStream()));
        //                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                    String inputLine;

                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                        response.append(inputLine);

                }
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return response.toString();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `BufferedReader` to read and `StringBuilder` to build required string..

```
protected String Method_Name(String... url){
String urls = url[0];    
String texts = "";      
 try{
     in = new java.net.URL(urls).openStream();    
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     String line = null;             
     while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
         sb.append(line + "\n");
     }
     texts = sb.toString();    
 }catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
 return texts;
}
```